# Minimum transaction value on token in solidity

Tags: transactions, tokens, binance

Is there a way of setting a minimum transaction value on token in solidity?
The point is that for transaction (purchase) to happen, the value has to be of some equivalent of ETH (say 0.2). Always. Smaller transactions should not happen. Is that possible somehow?